# Login and register linking in Breeze Layout

Tags: reactjs, laravel, breeze

I use Breeze with React. As you know, we have a component Welcome.jsx and this component displays links to login and register if we aren't logged otherwise - link to Dashboard. It looks like this

```
        <div className="fixed top-0 right-0 px-6 py-4 sm:block">
            {props.auth.user ? (
                <Link href={route('dashboard')} className="text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-500 underline">
                    Dashboard
                </Link>
            ) : (
                <>
                    <Link href={route('login')} className="text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-500 underline">
                        Log in
                    </Link>

                    <Link
                        href={route('register')}
                        className="ml-4 text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-500 underline"
                    >
                        Register
                    </Link>
                </>
            )}
        </div>
```

But this component is into Pages folder. This component in props has a auth value even though I don't send that from controller. In web.php it looks like this

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Welcome', [
        'canLogin' => Route::has('login'),
        'canRegister' => Route::has('register'),
        'laravelVersion' => Application::VERSION,
        'phpVersion' => PHP_VERSION,
     ]);
});
```

We have 2 layouts but interested for me is Guest. I need to change this layout and first and the most important thing at this moment is create navbar with login and register links, or links to user settings, etc if user isn't login. But I don't know how do that. So in console I have an error that props.auth doesn't exist. For a trial i copied component Welcome to Guest but effect is this same. How can I display links to login and register if user isn't log in and other menu if he is? But it the most important thing - not in Pages folder.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use something like they did on laravel-breeze-react repo

```
const Dashboard = () => {
const { logout, user } = useAuth({ middleware: 'auth' })

return (
    <>
        <p>{user?.name}</p>

        <button onClick={logout}>Sign out</button>
    </>
)
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all do you use useAuth from 'hooks/auth' on the parent components?

Where does the props.auth.user came from?

Comment: I don't know. Components from Pages folder has auth value in props automatically. I don't have idea from this come, so I ask you. I don't use useAuth becouse in Welcomewe don't have this.

Comment: Breeze and React use Inertia the props came from your controller.
You have two options: 
1.Keep working from welcome and pass the props you already have. 
2.Edit the controller to return the view you just created to access your props.

Comment: if you have any questions about issues that posts please ask them in comments